# Are suvey responses of ranking significantly different from mean ranking?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

I'm a stats dummy, so please use small words.  (-:
This might not be a valid test, so I'm sure you'll let me know if that's the case.

I have some survey responses in which the responses are rankings between 1 and 10.  I have a frequency for each ranking (2 1's, 3 2's, 2 3's, 10 4's and so on).

Intuitively, it looks like a lot of these responses fall in the middle and a few are on the tails, and I want to see if the reponses in the middle ranges are significantly different than the mean.  Is this a valid thing to do?  If so, whats the best (simple) test I can do?  I tried chi-squred, but a few of my rating categories have fewer than 5 responses, so is that valid?

Comment: What do you mean by "see if the responses in the middle ranges are significantly different than the mean"?  This needs to be clarified before this question can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to decide whether to treat the responses as if they are at the interval or ordinal level of measurement.  "Interval" would assume that the difference between 1 and 2 is the same as the difference between 2 and 3 (and so on all the way to the difference between 9 and 10).  "Ordinal" would relax that assumption.

With data treated as interval, you could conduct a *T*-test to compare the mean response against some hypothesized mean, such as 5.5.

With ordinal data, as you suggested you could run a Chi-square test, but expected cell counts fewer than 5 (not observed counts; a Chi-square primer will explain the difference)  would pose problems.  So you might need to collapse your categories into, say, 1 & 2, 3 & 4, etc.  Then the trick would be to test your distribution against some hypothesized distribution--what would that be?  To be true to (I believe) your idea of testing observed responses against hypothesized responses that centered on 5.5, perhaps you'd want to designate, using the same N, a normal-ish distribution that had high percentages of 5s & 6s, fewer of 3s & 4s and 7s & 8s, and fewer still of 1s & 2s and 9s & 10s.

Comment: Ah, now I'm tracking.  Thanks so much!  So, I added in a normal distribution and did the chi-squared test with that (I had just been using the mean).  It makes so much more sense now!  I did do the t-test first, but I felt like it didn't quite get at what I wanted to express, since it's just showing if the mean is different.  I want to show that people overall responded with more positive or negative rankings than, say, asking people on the street.  Do you think comparing my response distribution to a normdist is reasonable for this? (It's a survey my company sent out to employees).

Comment: It's important to look closely at your expectation of the responses from "people on the street."  On what are your expectations based? Also, I'm having trouble reconciling "a lot of these responses fall in the middle" with "[my sample] overall responded with more positive or negative rankings than [others did]."